Internal vs external structure (ETCS vs ZFC)
I was studying ETCS set theory when a question came to my mind.
In many presentations, ZFC is claimed to axiomatise sets by giving them an internal structure (the membership relation), while ETCS focuses on their external structure (the categorial mappings structure).
I honestly can't get the difference. Why would the membership relation be "more internal" than the morphism structure? For example, is an endomap an instance of internal or external structure?
Furthermore, ETCS sets are claimed to be heirs of Cantor's notion of lauter Einsen, units not structured at all, whereas ZFC sets to be closer to the intuitive notion of sets. This too could be clearer. In which sense are ETCS sets less structured? Formally they are all "variables", but once the theory is set, they end up being both structured (at least I suppose).

In the set theory, the sets are "transparent", you can peek inside and see their elements (and the elements of the elements and so on). With the $\in$ relation, you can explicitly investigate the internal structure of any set.
In ETCS the sets as objects are perfectly opaque. At first they do not have any internal structure whatsoever. All you see is arrows going in and out of the objects. The arrows are on the "outside", so they are external to the objects. So you can only infer the internal structure indirectly by examining the arrows. For example, if you see an object such that it has exactly one incoming arrow from any other object, you can deduce that such an object, considered as a set, has exactly one element. Similarly, you can reason about constructions such as products, coproducts, again by paying attention to the arrows.
The absolute magic and beauty of the category theory is that this external description turns out to be "complete", as expressed for example by the Yoneda Lemma. You do not lose any information by being limited to studying only arrows, "relationships" between objects.
The internal/external picture is also used when concepts about categories become themselves objects and arrows in a category. For example, you can "internalize" the arrow composition (external concept) as an actual arrow (an internal concept) between two exponential objects.

I added two words since otherwise I think your paragraph contains a contradiction. Feel free to revert if you meant something else.

@MartinBrandenburg you've made it clearer, thx!

@TonyDolezal I thank you for your answer, which sounds clear to me but still not fulfilling the question (it must be me). I can get the formal difference between a map and a relation, but I hardly conceive why the former is external and the latter internal. After all, e.g. in ZFC, the belonging relation always happens between a set and some other set which (at least somehow) exists a priori of being an element of that set: why would it be internal? Likewise, in ETCS there are elements, only set up not through a relation but as maps. If this leads you further, feel free to edit your reply.

@TonyDolezal Maybe some source of my misunderstanding is in that "at first". Taking it literally, also in ZFC sets are perfectly opaque at the beginning, namely before being wired with the belonging relation.

@AmandaWealth You are correct. If you remain at the FOL plane, working formally, abstractly, avoiding any interpretation, in that case relations are also "external". This internal/external business is not something precisely defined, it is using a loose, real world analogy, meant to improve our understanding and intuition. It relies heavily on our idea of sets as "bags of things".  Similarly, I don't believe "forgetful functor" is really something strictly defined, but we get it.

The category of sets in ZF admits an obvious faithful and essentially surjective on objects functor from a partially ordered class (namely, the class of all sets, partially ordered by inclusion), thanks to the global membership relation.
Following the general principle that faithful functors are forgetful functors from a category of more structured objects to a category of less structured objects, this is one sense in which ZF sets are more structured.
However, we can do something analogous for ETCS – it just takes much more effort and is highly non-canonical.
The idea is to axiomatise the transitive closure of a (pure, well founded) material set as a (directed) graph with special properties and then observe that (by the axiom of choice) each abstract set is isomorphic to one obtained from such a  graph.
(This is described in [Shulman, Comparing material and structural set theories]; I will briefly sketch it below.)
Thus, ironically, perhaps the point about material sets being more structured than abstract sets is that the category of material sets admits a canonical faithful and bijective-on-objects functor from a partially ordered class.
One might go as far as saying that the so-called category of sets in a material set theory is not the true category we should be considering (when studying material set theory), because it forgets the structure induced by the global membership relation.
But I think most mathematicians take the contrapositive and conclude that material sets have more structure than what we actually need.

As promised, let me sketch how we can "materialise" the abstract sets of ETCS.

A graph is a set (of nodes) equipped with a binary relation $\prec$.
(No conditions on $\prec$.)

Say a graph $T$ is well founded if, for all subsets $T' \subseteq T$ such that
$$\forall t . (\forall t' . t' \prec t \to t' \in T') \to t \in T'$$
we have $T' = T$.

Say a graph is extensional if, for all nodes $t'$ and $t''$:
$$(\forall t . t \prec t' \leftrightarrow t \prec t'') \leftrightarrow t' = t''$$

Given graphs $S$ and $T$, a simulation $S \to T$ is a map $f : S \to T$ with the following properties:

For all nodes $s$ and $s'$, $s \prec s'$ implies $f (s) \prec f (s')$.

For all nodes $t$ and $s'$, if $t \prec f (s')$, then there exists $s$ such that $f (s) = t$.




The above definitions make sense in any elementary topos, say $\mathcal{S}$, so we may form a category $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S})$ whose objects are the well-founded extensional graphs in $\mathcal{S}$ and whose morphisms are simulations.
It can be shown that $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S})$ is a preorder category: indeed, there is at most one simulation between any two well-founded extensional graphs.
There is an evident forgetful functor $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S}) \to \mathcal{S}$ which is faithful, conservative, an isofibration, and preserves pullbacks; assuming the axiom of choice in $\mathcal{S}$, it is even surjective on objects: after all, then every set can be well ordered and we can just take $\prec$ to be any (irreflexive) well-ordering.
However, $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S})$ is not the preorder category we really want – it is the analogue of the partially ordered class of all transitive sets, whereas we want the class of all sets.

An accessible pointed graph (henceforth, APG) is a graph equipped with a distinguished node $\top$ such that:

For every node $t$, there is a path from $t$ to $\top$, i.e. a finite sequence $(t_0, \ldots, t_n)$ of nodes such that $t_{i + 1} \prec t_i$ for all $0 \le i < n$, $t_0 = \top$, and $t_n = t$.
(We have $n = 0$ if and only if $t = \top$.)


Given an APG $T$, a member of $T$ is a node $t$ such that $t \prec \top$.
We denote by $\# T$ the set of members of $T$.

Given a graph $T$ and $t$ in $T$, denote by $T_{/ t}$ the full subgraph of $T$ consisting of all $t'$ such that there is a path from $t'$ to $t$.
(The trivial path counts, so $t$ is in $T_{/ t}$.)

Given well-founded extensional APGs $S$ and $T$, say a map $f : S \to T$ models subset inclusion if it has the following properties:

$f (\top) = \top$.

For all nodes $s$ and $s'$, if $s \prec s'$, then $f (s) \prec f (s')$.

For all nodes $s$, if $s \prec \top$, then the induced map $S_{/ s} \to T_{/ f (s)}$ is an isomorphism (of graphs).




Going forward, we should assume $\mathcal{S}$ has an NNO.
Let $\mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S})$ be the category whose objects are well-founded extensional APGs in $\mathcal{S}$ and whose morphisms are maps that model subset inclusion.
$\mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S})$ is a preorder category: given a map $f : S \to T$ modelling subset inclusion, $f$ restricts to a simulation $S \setminus \{ \top \} \to T \setminus \{ \top \}$; but both $S \setminus \{ \top \}$ and $T \setminus \{ \top \}$ are well-founded extensional graphs, so there is at most one map $S \to T$ modelling subset inclusion.
We have a functor $\# : \mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S}) \to \mathcal{S}$, and it is clearly faithful and conservative.
Furthermore, for every $T$ in $\mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S})$, the induced functor $\mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S})_{/ T} \to \mathcal{S}_{/ \# T}$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective onto the subcategory of monomorphisms into $\# T$.
Assuming the axiom of choice in $\mathcal{S}$, $\#$ is essentially surjective on objects (onto $\mathcal{S}$) too: in fact, we have (without the axiom of choice) a functor $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S}) \to \mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S})$ such that postcomposing with $\#$ is isomorphic to the forgetful functor $\mathbf{W} (\mathcal{S}) \to \mathcal{S}$, so we are just reducing to the previous assertion.
(However, if $\mathcal{S}$ is the category of sets in ZF, then $\# : \mathbf{V} (\mathcal{S}) \to \mathcal{S}$ is essentially surjective on objects even without assuming the axiom of choice.
We do not even need the full strength of ZF – Mac Lane set theory minus choice suffices – the key point is that for every set $X$ we just need to construct the transitive closure of $\{ X \}$ to get a well-founded extensional APG $T$ such that $\# T \cong X$ canonically.)
